# Does using nginx as a reverse proxy require backend services to be public

Tags: nginx

The title might not be the best explanation.  If I have nginx setup as a reverse proxy, listening on a public address, do the backend services sitting behind nginx need to be listening on a public address too, or can they remain listening on private addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backend services can remain listening on private addresses.

By the way, this is the most common setup : the reverse proxy will act as a gateway between external network and your internal network.

Exposing backend services on the external network would make no much sense, because they could be reached direclty, by-passing the reverse proxy.

However, make sure that your nginx box is setup so that its routing table allows you to reach your internal network. Usually you have two network interface : one external, one internal.

Finally, for security concern, put your backend servers in a dedicated DMZ and not directly onto your LAN.